# pointer arithmetic confusion with number and address

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused as to how to work out the solution for this:

```
4 - (( h + 4 ) - &h[6]) + &h[2] + 5 + (&h[3] - (h+6))
```

my approach is:

```
4 - (( &h[4] - &h[6]) + &h[2] + 5 + (&h[3] - &h[6])) // &h[4] - &h[6] + &h[2] = 0 (is this correct?)
4 - ( 0 + 5 + (&h[3] - &h[6])) // &h[3] - &h[6] = -3 
4 - ( 5 -3)) //
4 - ( 2))
2
```

but this is not correct

Comment: What is `h` and what exactly do you mean to "work out"?

Comment: However I don't see how this could possibly be valid code, you cannot subtract a pointer from an integer, only the other way round

Comment: Fortunately normal C programming never involves code like this.  (In other words, this is a *highly* artificial exercise.)

Answer (score 4):

I see it like this:

```
   4 - (( h + 4 ) - &h[6]) + &h[2] + 5 + (&h[3] - (h + 6))
//int    ptr int     ptr      ptr   int    ptr    ptr int

// convert &a[i] to (a + i)
   4 - (( h + 4 ) - (h + 6)) + (h + 2) + 5 + ((h + 3) - (h + 6))
//int    ptr int    ptr int    ptr int  int   ptr int   ptr int

   4 - (-2) + (h + 2) + 5 + (-3)
//int  int    ptr int  int   int

   6 + (h + 2) + 2
//int  ptr int  int

   h + 10
//ptr int --- same as &h[10]
```

Comment: [ideone](https://ideone.com/ZM8o1L) agrees with me :)